# Wordpress and pluigin CM Tooltip Glossary

Tags: redirect, wordpress

I've problem with this plugin : CM Tooltip Glossary. When i click 'add new', on fev second it's form with this plugin, and when all page loaded, it's refresh again and redirect me to original form from wordpress. In form from cm glossary should be one text with title and textare with description, but it's two text with english title, and polish title, and textare, so i've a question why wordpress redirect me to ohter form ?

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out with redirect, responsible for this, was that line: include ('. / admin-footer.php');  in file : wp-admin/post.php :)